# AngularJs doesn't update the model when the input data is changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, modal-dialog

I have angular application which uses directives.
In the directive I have template that defines pop up modal.

Basically, it's very simple app that shows a list of book authors, and in the list there is an *Edit* button that opens *modal box*.
If I open the modal for editing the book author, and just close it, without editing the author - there is no problem.

But if I open the modal, and type something in the author input, and close it, the model is stuck with the current input value for the whole time, so if I open another author for editing, the model will not be updated.

My question is: why is this happening, and how to fix it ?

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table class="table table-hover">
            <tr>              
                <td><b>Publisher</b></td>                
                <td><b>Edit Publisher</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="book in books">
                <td>
                    {{book.Author}}
                </td>
                 <td>
                    <span ng-click="toggleModal(book)" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    <modal-dialog info='modalShown' show='modalShown' width='600px' height='60%'>
        <div ng-show="divBook">
              <input type="text" name="bookAuthor" ng-model="bookAuthor" />
        </div>
    </modal-dialog>
</div>
```

Angular

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.books = [{Author:"Jon Skeet"},{Author:"John Papa"},{Author:"Scott Hanselman"}];

    $scope.modalShown = false;
     $scope.toggleModal = function (book) {
          $scope.bookAuthor = book.Author;
          $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;
          $scope.divBook = true;
    };    
});

myApp.directive('modalDialog', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: "<div  class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'>"
                    +"<div class='ng-modal-overlay' ng-click='hideModal()'>"
                     +"</div>"
                      +"<div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'>"
                      +"<div class='ng-modal-close' ng-click='hideModal()'>X</div>"
                      +"<div class='ng-modal-dialog-content' ng-transclude>"
                     +"</div>"
                    +"</div>"
                +"div>",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            show: '=info'
        },
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            //scope.apply();
            scope.dialogStyle = {};
            if (attrs.width)
                scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.width;
            if (attrs.height)
                scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.height;
            scope.hideModal = function () {
                scope.show = false;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

So, the test case will be:

Click Edit -> change the value -> close the modal

Click Edit on another author.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/17694/

Answer (score 0):

The model value is changing, however you are creating a new variable and not modifying the original element of the array.

You can change that by putting a pointer of the array object in a scope variable

```
$scope.toggleModal = function (book) {
      $scope.book = book;
      $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;
      $scope.divBook = true;
};
```

then pointing the ng-model to the .Author property of the object.

```
<input type="text" name="bookAuthor" ng-model="book.Author" />
```

See modified JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9a2jcc9u/1/

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your JS fiddle, if you want to change name and it automatically changes in grid than remove angular.copy(book) and directly assign book. you can see your jsfiddle here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/17695/)

```
    myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.books = [{Author:"Jon Skeet"},{Author:"John Papa"},{Author:"Scott Hanselman"}];

    $scope.modalShown = false;
     $scope.toggleModal = function (book) {
           $scope.book = angular.copy(book);
          $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;
          $scope.divBook = true;
    };    
});
```

your modal dialog

```
<modal-dialog info='modalShown' show='modalShown' width='600px' height='60%'>
    <div ng-show="divBook">
          <input type="text" name="bookAuthor" ng-model="book.Author" />
    </div>
</modal-dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {

//your code

}]);
```